Let $a,b,c,d$ be the roots of the quartic polynomial $f(x)=x^4+2x+4$.Find $\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}+\frac{b^2}{b^3+2}+\frac{c^2}{c^3+2}+\frac{d^2}{d^3+2}$
Let $a,b,c,d$ be the roots of the quartic polynomial $f(x)=x^4+2x+4$.Find $\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}+\frac{b^2}{b^3+2}+\frac{c^2}{c^3+2}+\frac{d^2}{d^3+2}$
My attempt: first I multiply each fraction by $\frac aa,\cdots$ and get $$\frac{a^3}{a^4+2a}+\frac{b^3}{b^4+2b}+\frac{c^3}{c^4+2c}+\frac{d^3}{d^4+2d}$$ then w.r.t. $x^4+2x=-4 \to a^4+2a=-4,b^4+2b=-4,c^4+2c=-4,d^4+2d=-4$ so,we hae to find $$\frac{a^3}{=4}+\frac{b^3}{-4}+\frac{c^3}{-4}+\frac{d^3}{-4}=\frac{-1}{4}(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)$$ then I tried to rewrite the equation $x^4+2x+4=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$  so $$a+b+c+d=0\\ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=0\\ abc + abd + acd + bcd=-2\\abcd=4$$ But I get stuck to find a relation between $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$ and roots relation (above)
When I tried to expand $(a+b+c+d)^3$  there are some terms like $a^2b,...$ which I don't know how to deal with them.
Thanks in advance for any hints or Ideas.

Isn't abc + abd + acd + bcd = -2 ?

@Gwen: Sure I fix it thank you.

Hint: use $x^3=-2-\frac{4}{x}$

@DavidQuinn: Thank you very much.

I like that you tried so well. I'm using your info.
So you know yourself that your Answer, say $z$ can be written as
$$z =\frac{-1}{4}(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3)$$
Now back to original equation
$$x^4 + 2x + 4 =0 \implies x^4 = -2x - 4 $$
Or (by dividing both sides by $x$)
$$x^3=-2-\frac{4}{x}$$
Substituting this for $a,b,c,d$ gives
$$z=\frac{-1}{4}(-2-\frac{4}{a}-2-\frac{4}{b}-2-\frac{4}{c}-2-\frac{4}{d})$$
After simplifying, this is actually
$$z=2+(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d})$$
Or
$$z=2+(\frac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}+\frac{1}{d})$$
But as you already know, $$ab+bc+ca+da+db+dc=0 \implies ab+bc+ac=-d(a+b+c)$$ but
$$a+b+c=-d \implies -d(a+b+c)=d^2$$ also
$$abcd=4 \implies abc =\frac{4}{d}$$
So substituting these we get,
$$z=2+(\frac{d^3}{4}+\frac{1}{d})=2+(\frac{d^4+4}{4d})$$
Putting $d$ in original eqn, we get $$\frac{d^4+4}{4d}=\frac{-1}{2}$$
So your answer must be $2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$. Is it correct?

$$a^3=-2-\frac4{a},...\a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=-2-\frac4{a}-2-\frac4{b}-2-\frac4{c}-2-\frac4{d}\=-16-4(\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c+\frac 1d)\=-16-4(\frac{ abc + abd + acd + bcd}{abcd})=-16-4\frac {-2}{4}$$s o the answer is $$\frac {-1}{4}(-14)$$

It should be -8, not -16. Also yes this is the shortest method, I overlooked it. @Khosrotash

I like your solution, but something is wrong I think, I am trying your method and compare

@Khosrotash Of course you're free to do that.  But your process gives the same answer of $\frac{3}{2} $ as well.

Something in my solution is not correct.?  I don't get it .

Your method is correct of course. Both of us come to the same value? Do you have the answer somewhere in printed form?

Take a look at Newton's identities.
In particular, $p_3 = e_1p_2 -e_2p_1+3e_3$, i.e. $$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 = (a+b+c+d)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) - (ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)(a+b+c+d)+3(abc+abd+acd+bcd).$$ The only unknown is then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, but then you have $p_2 = e_1p_1-2e_2$, i.e. $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = (a+b+c+d)^2-2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd).$$
From Vieta's formulas we have $e_1 = 0$, $e_2 = 0$, $e_3 = -2$, $e_4 = 4$ and therefore $p_1 = e_1 = 0$, $p_2 = e_1p_1-2e_2 = 0$ and $p_3 = e_1p_2-e_2p_1+3e_3 = -6$.
